# Erro ao usar Slick.js em modal Jquery

Tags: jquery, modal, slider

Estou com problema na utilização do [Slick JS](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) , Estou criando uma lista de imagens que trago do banco de dados com PHP.

```
<ul id="imagemProdContainer" class="imagemProdContainer">
<?php
  if(!empty($galeria)):
    foreach($galeria as $foto):
?>
 <li data-legenda="<?=$foto->legenda;?>">
  <button href="#" id="btnFechaProd" class="btnFechaProd">X</button>
  <img src="assets/uploads/<?=$foto->imagem;?>" alt="<?=$foto->legenda;?>">
  <span><?=$foto->legenda;?></span>
 </li>
<?php
    endforeach;
 endif;
?>
</ul>
```

Sendo este um modal que fica com display none, e só aparece quando clico em uma galeria de miniaturas, que por sua vez também é um slick (miniaturas para clicar e abrir o modal):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ao clicar em alguma das imagens, o que me retorna é o modal com a imagem carregada apenas no DOM, mas não na janela em si:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando tenho alguma interação como resize, passar para o próximo slide ou click a imagem aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está a declaração do Java Script:

```
// Galeria Detalhe/Amplia Produtos
{
(function(){
    $('#galeriaProdutos li').on('click touch', function(event){
            var modalImagem = $('#imagemProdContainer'),
            index = $(this).data('slide');

        setTimeout(function(){
                modalImagem.addClass('active');                 
        }, 8);

        setTimeout(function(){
                $('#imagemProdContainer').slick('slickGoTo', index);            
        }, 5);

    });

    $('#imagemProdContainer').on('click touch', function (event){
        var idModal = $(this).attr('id');

        if(idModal == event.target.id){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
})();
}


 // Fechar Galeria Detalhes/Amplia Produtos
{
    (function(){
     btnFecharDetalhe = $('.btnFechaProd');

     btnFecharDetalhe.on('click touch', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#imagemProdContainer').removeClass('active');
     });
    })();
}

// Slick Galeria Detalhe/Amplia Produto
{
 $('#imagemProdContainer').slick({
    fade: true,
    arrow: true
 });
}
```

Adicionei um set timeout para ver se resolvia e nada, tentei verificar o carregamento do slick com on load e nada, estou desenvolvendo e o site está no ar em um link temporário, este é o link para a página com o problema em questão:

http://agenciasayhello.com.br/clientes/svetlana/produto/jardim-vertical

Espero que consigam me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como na documentação do plugin não informa nenhum evento quando o slider é ativado, você pode disparar um evento `resize` na função dos eventos `click touch` abaixo, sem a necessidade de usar `setTimeout` e outros códigos que inseriu.

A função do evento deve ficar assim:

```
// Galeria Detalhe/Amplia Produtos
{
   (function(){
      $('#galeriaProdutos li').on('click touch', function(event){
         var modalImagem = $('#imagemProdContainer');
         modalImagem.addClass('active');                    

         // dispara o resize
         $(window).trigger("resize");
      });

      $('#imagemProdContainer').on('click touch', function (event){
         var idModal = $(this).attr('id');

         if(idModal == event.target.id){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
         }
      });
   })();
}
```

Comment: Funcionou muito obrigado! Porém mantive o `$('#imagemProdContainer').slick('slickGoTo', index);` para alterar para imagem correspondente a miniatura.

Comment: Ah sim... que bom que resolveu!

Answer (score 0):

Corrigido com a ajuda do amigo DVD Código final:

```
    // Galeria Detalhe/Amplia Produtos
    {
        (function(){
          $('#galeriaProdutos li').on('click touch', function(event){
            var modalImagem = $('#imagemProdContainer'),
            index = $(this).data('slide');

            $('#imagemProdContainer').slick('slickGoTo', index);
            modalImagem.addClass('active');
            $(window).trigger("resize");


         });

       $('#imagemProdContainer').on('click touch', function (event){
         var idModal = $(this).attr('id');

        if(idModal == event.target.id){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
       });
      })();
    }
```

Obrigado!